# How to use the たり form?

Tags: grammar

Does たり have any other meanings or translations than "I do things like…and …"?

Comment: In classical Japanese, 〜たり is stative / perfective form of verbs (ancestor of modern 〜た form). Possibly still used in this way in archaic style in modern language... (Simple past tense was formed by completely different 〜き／〜し／〜しき suffix.)

Comment: The following should  answer your question. [-た and -たり meaning and etymology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98186)